# Access Abstract Class Property dynamically (the Class)

Tags: php

Given there are Abstract Classes and I want to access certain properties from different classes and I want a user Interface that the user might enter the class and the property.

Is there any better way than

```
$_class = "CLASSNAME";
$_prop  = "FILE";

$_eval = "return (" . $_class . "::$" . $_prop . ");"; 
$_val = eval( $_eval );
```

If the Class will be known (or only one class exists), I could use

```
$_val = CLASSNAME::$$_prop;
```

But how to replace CLASSNAME?

Comment: I believe you mean **static** properties, not *abstract*?!

Answer (score -1):

May you find the power of [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and relize the error of using [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) (should be pronounced like "evil")